# Selective dates in Date Picker for Storyboard (iOS Development)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker, storyboard

Is it possible to restrict DatePicker to selective dates with a given range in iOS storyboard ?
I'm trying to make the DatePicker display only Saturdays.

Comment: Maybe You will need to create custom Calender.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in Storyboard, nor with a `UIDatePicker`...

But, pretty simple to do with a `UIPickerView`.

- get the date for "this Saturday"
- for each row, return thisSaturday plus (7 x row)

Here's a quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var thisSaturday: Date!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // set your desired date format
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(picker)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // center picker view with default width and height
            picker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            picker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self

        // get the date for the "upcoming Saturday"
        
        let today = Date()
        let daysToAdd = 7 - (Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: today).weekday ?? 0 )
        guard let d = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysToAdd, to: today) else {
            fatalError("Could not get a valid date!!! (This should never happen...)")
        }

        thisSaturday = d

    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        // how many weeks in the future do you want to allow?
        //  for example, 52-weeks x 4-years
        return 52 * 4
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        // each row will be
        //  "upcoming Saturday" plus
        //  7-days x row number
        guard let d = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7 * row, to: thisSaturday) else {
            fatalError("Could not get a valid date!!! (This should never happen...)")
        }
        return dateFormatter.string(from: d)
    }
    
}
```